# Why doesn't memory overflow occur while Dictionary Initialization?

Tags: java, c#, dictionary, data-structures, hash

**Background :** Dictionary uses a Hash Function to generate an index for every value you enter.

1. While saying index is unique in case of every input , I was just
   wondering what could be the exact Hash function which generate
   unique value for every input ?
2. Let's assume ( As I am not Sure about it) , there exist a hash function which generates unique index for every input. Then of what size would the Dictionary will be initialized ? I'm assuming it is dynamic, but what if one index is 10 and for another input it is 123456? It has to use an array of size 123457 - wouldn't that result in memory overflow ?

PS : I have theoretical knowledge of what Hash function is and what it does, but I haven't seen its actual implementation. Also, as many languages have built-in data structures for this purpose, it made me curios :)

Comment: Are you asking about Java or C#?

Comment: Any one. I am more interested in implementation than a specific language ?

Comment: Both questions #1 and #2 relate to a specific type of hashing, i.e. "perfect hash". In general, it's _not_ true that you get a hash function that returns a unique value for every input. As far as the "overflow" question, this doesn't happen because a hash table's length has nothing to do with the range of values returned by the hash function. Any more in-depth discussion of this question is really off-topic here. You will be better off reading Wikipedia or other references.

Comment: Obviously I did google before writing this long question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assumption regarding the uniqueness of the hash function is wrong.

If we take, for example, `HashMap` of Java, it uses the `hashCode()` of the key and applies a supplemental hash function on it (to defend against poor quality hash functions). Then is takes the calculated hash value and maps it to an index in the storage of the map, which is typically much smaller than the hash value.

Therefore, even if the hash function would return a unique value for each key (which it is not required to), `HashMap` would still normalize that value to a much smaller index of the storage of the `HashMap`. Therefore there is no overflow (as long as you don't insert too many elements into the `Map`).

Comment: What Happens if you get same index for different inputs after normalizing ? I have read, in that case you look for next empty index or similar. ( Correct me if I am wrong ). Doubt here is while retrieving how will I know that it is right index or i need to look for next ?

Comment: @Manish The way HashMap is implemented, an index in the map contains a linked list of all the (key,value) pairs that were mapped to it. Once you reach the linked list of an index, you iterate over the list until you find the key you are looking for. The idea is that in average the lists will be very short compared to the total number of elements in the map, and therefore the lookup would take O(1) on average.